# React Ant Design Table - multiple (column) row selection

Tags: reactjs, antd

Ant Design has a `rowSelection` [feature](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-row-selection-and-operation) to use on their `<Table />` element, and looks like so:
[image: Ant Design Original]

I don't see anywhere that would indicate a multi-column row selection, like so:
[image: Ant Design / altered image]

I've checked out [this](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/11404) Github issue that I thought was asking the same thing, and [this](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/commit/08e83193f2248e8c960bb66e760a1d850034bd50) PR that supposedly addressed it, but I cannot figure out how it supposed to be used (perhaps I'm mistaken that it has been implemented).

Is this currently possible to achieve using existing Ant Design code, or would something custom need to be implemented?

**Version:** We are using Ant Design 3.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `antd` code you can make some kind of mix between [Multiple Row selection](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-row-selection) and [Editable cell/row](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell) (with checkbox instead of inputs)

But I'm afraid you can't make various selectable columns. At least the documentation does not mention anything like this.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I didn’t find anything either.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in table Column Array, you can do this

```
  {
    title: "Can Do Y ", 
    key: "canDoY",
    width: 100,
    render: val => <Checkbox value={val}> </Checkbox>
  }
```